# Link with another prefix on a Previously prefixed page in cakephp:2.5.4

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-routing

I am trying to achieve the link as `cake_proj/prefix2/controller2/action` on this page who's link is - `cake-proj/` but `'prefix1' => true` in my `routes.php` as this is the `home` page, so ultimately its link is `cake_proj/prefix1/controller1/action`. So now I am trying to achieve `cake_proj/prefix2/controller2/action` with the help of Html helper's link method-

```
<?php
  echo $this->Html->link(
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-group"></i> Test Link', array(
      'prefix' => 'prefix2',
      'controller' => 'controller2',
      'action' => 'prefix_action'), array(
      'escape' => FALSE)
   );
 ?>
```

But with this I am getting the link as `cake_proj/prefix1/controller2/prefix_action` notice here it doesn't change the prefix. I don't want to loose the CakePHP's routing capability, but still want to get over this problem. I referred some of the previously answered questions but not worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution for you.. though not tested works perfectly for me. Here is the solution, cheers!

in **AppController.php**

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->set('prefixUsed',$this->request->prefix);
}
```

in **your_view.ctp**

```
<?php
  echo $this->Html->link(
    '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-group"></i> Test Link', array(
      $prefixUsed => false,
      'prefix2' => true
      'controller' => 'controller2',
      'action' => 'prefix_action'), array(
      'escape' => FALSE)
   );
 ?>
```

Here the idea is to set a variable `$prefixUsed` in `AppController.php` to be used by each and every views and even by layouts in `beforeFilter()`, and then using that variable into views to set it to false and making your desired `'prefix' => true`. We are using `$prefixUsed` to dynamically determine the prefix. Let me know if this worked or not for you, till then GoodBye... ;)